# Check if connection to YouTube is blocked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube, internet-connection

Some companies have blocking YouTube in their local networks, but we do web-applications for them, showing some helpful videos on YouTube. Sometimes it is better for our business to give the link to youtube even when connection is blocked, so I was need a way to check if that connection exists.

I didn't found such solution here, so maybe my solution will be helpful for somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check if connection to YouTube (for example) not blocked - to load some javascript lib from that site and check if it was loaded correctly:

Async loading of example lib (may be in script tag in your document):

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

That script is less than 1kB. When you need to check it in your javascript, use the following:

```
if (window.YT) 
   ...
```